# Python Web Scraping 'None'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I'm attempting to scrape event data from the site https://10times.com/losangeles-us/technology/conferences.

The code below goes ahead and scrapes event data and event links found on the main landing page.

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://10times.com/losangeles-us/technology/conferences').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

aa = []
bb = []

#---Get Event Data---
table = soup.find('tbody')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr') #find table rows (tr)
for x in table_rows:   
    data = x.find_all('td')  #find table data
    row = [x.text for x in data]
    if len(row) > 2: #Exlcudes rows with only event name/link, but no data.
        aa.append(row)
df_event = pd.DataFrame(aa, columns=['Date', 'Event Name', 'Venue', 'Description', 'Type', 'Unnamed:'])
df_event.columns = ['Date', 'Event Name', 'Venue', 'Description', 'Type', 'Interested/Following Count']

#---Get Links---
h2 = soup.find_all('h2')
for i in h2:
    links = i.a['href']
    bb.append(links)
df_link = pd.DataFrame(bb)
df_link.columns = ['Links']

#---Combines dfs---#
df = pd.concat([df_event,df_link],sort=False, axis=1)
df.index += 1       

#--Export to HTML---
df.to_html('10times_Scrape.html',render_links=True)
```

I'm now wanting to go to each of the event links I pulled and scrape the Address / full event description found on the page. ***Example link:*** https://10times.com/microsoft-business-applications-summit-anaheim

Both the event description and the address are both found in P tags. However, when I read in the links, I'm just returning None's.. I'm using the right div class below? What am I doing wrong? I would like to look into 'class':'col-md-6' and extract the address.

```
#---Get Address---
for i in bb:
    soup2 = bs.BeautifulSoup(i, 'html.parser')
    text2 = soup2.find('div', attrs={'class':'col-md-6'})
    print(text2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you missed the `urllib` fetching of the inner links.

```
#---Get Address---
for i in bb:
    inner_source = urllib.request.urlopen(i).read()

    soup2 = bs.BeautifulSoup(inner_source, 'html.parser')
    text2 = soup2.find('div', 'col-md-6')
    print(text2)
```

Also with `find`/`find_all` you can pass a class as the second positional param. And just to enforce that `find` will only return the first occurrence even if there are many.